# Fragment Bundle Does Not Work (With Onclick Procedure)

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to send a data from main activity to fragment. But i could not this. my code is here.

main activty

```
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                String mesajim="Bu sana disaridan gelen mesajdir.";
                bundle.putString("mesaj",mesajim);
                UrunAc fragment2 = new UrunAc();
                fragment2.setArguments(bundle);
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction2 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction2.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment2);
                fragmentTransaction2.commit();
                return true;
```

and my fragment code

```
package com.technotalkative.navigationviewdemo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
```

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */

```
public class UrunAc extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

public View goster;
public String mesaj;
public TextView tw ;


public UrunAc() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mesaj =this.getArguments().getString("mesaj");

    goster = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_urun,container,false);

    Button tiklat = (Button)goster.findViewById(R.id.tiklasana);
    tiklat.setOnClickListener(this);

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_urun, container, false);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    tw.setText(mesaj);

}
```

}

my button onclick listener does not work. thanks for your help.

i change but it gives an error like here :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.technotalkative.navigationviewdemo, PID: 3745
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                  at com.technotalkative.navigationviewdemo.UrunAc.onClick(UrunAc.java:49)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mesaj =this.getArguments().getString("mesaj");

    goster = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_urun,container,false);

    tw = (TextView)goster.findViewById(R.id.tw);// Change your tw id 

    Button tiklat = (Button)goster.findViewById(R.id.tiklasana);
    tiklat.setOnClickListener(this);

    return goster;// here is the problem
}
```

Comment: it's ok. thank you..i add this code line "tw =(TextView)goster.findViewById(R.id.bilgilerim);" and problem has solved.thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your click listener may not be working because you are returning a new `view` instance from your `onCreateView()`. Change it to:

```
return goster;
```

Comment: it's ok. thank you..i add this code line "tw =(TextView)goster.findViewById(R.id.bilgilerim);" and problem has solved.thank you.